# Convert Floating point value to percentage in Db2 SQL Query

Tags: db2-luw

I want to convert floating point values to percentage values from the below DB2 SQL query.

```
db2 "select STANDBY_SPOOL_PERCENT from table(MON_GET_HADR(NULL))"
```

The output of the above query is.

```
STANDBY_SPOOL_PERCENT   
------------------------
  +0.00000000000000E+000
```

But want to convert the floating point value +0.00000000000000E+000 to  percent.

**STANDBY_SPOOL_PERCENT** column data type is **DOUBLE**

Answer (score 0):

you could cast the double to a decimal, for example like this:

```
db2 "select decimal(STANDBY_SPOOL_PERCENT,5,2) from table(MON_GET_HADR(NULL))"
```